# Append/push an entire table into another table in html

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, append

I have two table like this

**Table 1**

```
+----------------------------------------
|   just        |         |    Many 1   |
|               |    Ket  |-------------|
|   desc        |         | 1 |  2 |  3 | 
+---------------+---------+-------------+
|     01        |  Kej    |   |    |    | 
|               |---------|-------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |
+---------------+------------------------
|     02        |  Kej    |   |    |    | 
|               |---------|-------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |
+---------------+------------------------
|     03        |  Kej    |   |    |    | 
|               |---------|-------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |
+---------------+------------------------
|     04        |  Kej    |   |    |    | 
|               |---------|-------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |
+---------------+------------------------
|     05        |  Kej    |   |    |    | 
|               |---------|-------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |
+---------------+------------------------
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
              <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
              <td colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</td>
              
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
              <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
              <td>TP s/d Bulan ini</td>
             
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">01</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         
           <tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">05</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
            <tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">02</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
            <tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">03</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">04</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

**Table 2**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|   just        |         |   Many 2        |
|               |    Ket  |-----------------|
|   desc        |         |  1  |  2  |  3  | 
+---------------+---------+-----------------+
|     01        |  Kej    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |     |     |     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
|     02        |  Kej    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |     |     |     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
|     03        |  Kej    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |     |     |     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
|     04        |  Kej    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |     |     |     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
|     05        |  Kej    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |     |     |     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
      
      <td colspan="3">TP yang ditindak lanjuti (TP)</td>
      <td rowspan="2">TPB s/d Bulan Ini</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
      <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
      <td>SUB TOTAL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">01</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
            <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">05</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
             <td></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">02</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
             <td></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">03</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">04</td>
           <td>Kejadian</td> 
           <td ></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td> 
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Rp</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
    
    </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So i have to combine the table 2 into table 1,i need the data from the third column to fift column of table 2 into the next of the fifth column of table 1 just like the code below.

**Table 1 + Table 2**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|   just        |         |    Many 1   |   Many 2        |
|               |    Ket  |-------------|-----------------|
|   desc        |         | 1 |  2 |  3 |  1  |  2  |  3  | 
+---------------+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|     01        |  Kej    |   |    |    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-------------+-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |     |     |     |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
|     02        |  Kej    |   |    |    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-------------+-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |     |     |     |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
|     03        |  Kej    |   |    |    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-------------+-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |     |     |     |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
|     04        |  Kej    |   |    |    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-------------+-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |     |     |     |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
|     05        |  Kej    |   |    |    |     |     |     | 
|               |---------|-------------+-----------------+
|               |  Rp     |   |    |    |     |     |     |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Could somebody help me with this, I don't know how to take the table 2 data column and push it in into table 1 just like I expect?

Comment: How're you creating these tables? Are the tables just written like this, or do you dynamically create them using some code? Can you create a JSON object out of the data?

Comment: I create both table using foreach on php. I made those two tables separately. after i done foreach the data for both table in `php` i append the `table 2` data into `table 1` @31piy. just it.

Comment: let's say both tables were made just like that from the first, so there is nothing to do with JSON/array/the actual data, i guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My jQuery Solution

```
var el = $("#table2 thead tr:eq(0) td:eq(2)").clone();
$("#table1 thead tr:eq(0)").append(el);

$("#table2 thead tr:eq(1) td").each(function () {
    $("#table1 thead tr:eq(1)").append($(this).clone());
});

$('#table2 tbody tr').each(function (index) {
    $(this).find('td:nth-last-child(2), td:nth-last-child(3), td:nth-last-child(4)').each(function () {
        $("#table1 tbody").find("tr:eq(" + index + ")").append($(this).clone());
    });
});
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/4moGtn?p=preview

JavaScript Solution

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('table1');
var table2 = document.getElementById('table2');

var cell = (table2.tHead.rows[0].cells[2]).cloneNode(true);
table1.tHead.rows[0].appendChild(cell);

for(var i = 0, cells = table2.tHead.rows[1].cells; i < cells.length; i++) {
    table1.tHead.rows[1].appendChild( cells[i].cloneNode(true) );
}

for(var i = 0, rows = table2.tBodies[0].rows; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].cells, rowTable1 = table1.tBodies[0].rows[i];

    if(i%2)
        rowTable1.appendChild(cells[1].cloneNode(true));

        rowTable1.appendChild(cells[2].cloneNode(true));
        rowTable1.appendChild(cells[3].cloneNode(true));

    if(i%2 == 0)
        rowTable1.appendChild(cells[4].cloneNode(true));
}
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/z67BEo?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

#### Check out this DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37574/

I added a button click event just to differentiate between before and after combination.

First of all, your table preparing php code is wrong in tbody part, you need a closing `tr` tag.

#### Wrong HTML Output

```
       <tr>
       <td>Rp</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     
       <tr> <-- ***** HERE ***** -->
       <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">05</td>
       <td>Kejadian</td> 
       <td ></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td> 
       </tr>
```

Then call the table combination function when you need it.

My code is not pretty though, because there are thead part, and tbody also have rowspan part.

*But you got the idea and the working script.

#### JQUERY

```
$('#btn_combine').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide(0);
    combineTable();
});

function combineTable() {
    // prepare thead first
    $('#tbl_1 thead tr').eq(0).append('<td colspan="3">' + $('#tbl_2 thead tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(2).text() + '</td>');

    var th1 = $('#tbl_2 thead tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(0).text();
    var th2 = $('#tbl_2 thead tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(1).text();
    var th3 = $('#tbl_2 thead tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(2).text();
    $('#tbl_1 thead tr').eq(1).append('<td>' + th1 + '</td><td>' + th2 + '</td><td>' + th3 + '</td>');

    // prepare tbody
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            var r1_td1 = $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(2).text();
            var r1_td2 = $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(3).text();
            var r1_td3 = $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(4).text();

            var e = '<td>' + r1_td1 + '</td><td>' + r1_td2 + '</td><td>' + r1_td3 + '</td>';
        } else {
            var r2_td1 = $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(1).text();
            var r2_td2 = $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(2).text();
            var r2_td3 = $('#tbl_2 tbody tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(3).text();

            var e = '<td>' + r2_td1 + '</td><td>' + r2_td2 + '</td><td>' + r2_td3 + '</td>';
        }
        $('#tbl_1 tbody tr').eq(i).append(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution consist on two steps:

1. **Merging the Header**

At this step I will select only te desired columns & merge them with the first table, as you know we don't have to copy this columns:

```
    +-------------------------+
    |   just        |         |
    |               |    Ket  |
    |   desc        |         | 
    +---------------+---------+
```

So I will use this code to say that in the first row we just want to add the last column, however in the second row we'll add all the columns:

```
//Merging the header of the table
    var cpt=0;
    $("#table1 thead tr").each(function(){
        if(cpt==0){//For the first row we want just to add the last column
            $(this).append($("#table2 thead tr:first td:last"));
        }else{//However in the second row we add all the columns
            $(this).append($("#table2 thead tr:last ").html());
        }
        cpt++;
    });
```

2. **Mergin the Body**
   We can see that the `body` contains two kinds of `tr`:

   - The first one is composed by **two** first row that have a content
   - The second one is composed by just **one** first row that have a content
     I think that those columns, so I used the [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) function to avoid selecting theme:

   cpt=0;
       $("#table1 tbody tr").each(function(i, el){

   ```
       var lines=$("#table2 tbody ").find("tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").find("td");
       if (i % 2 === 0) {
           var lines=$("#table2 tbody ").find("tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").find("td").slice( 2 );
           $(this).append(lines);
       }else {
           var lines=$("#table2 tbody ").find("tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").find("td").slice(1);
           $(this).append(lines);
       }
   });
   ```

Finally, I invite you to check the following code snippet to see if my solution is what you expected when you post your question:

```js
$(function(){

        //Merging the header of the table
        var cpt=0;
        $("#table1 thead tr").each(function(){
            if(cpt==0){//For the first row we want just to add the last column
                $(this).append($("#table2 thead tr:first td:last"));
            }else{//However in the second row we add all the columns
                $(this).append($("#table2 thead tr:last ").html());
            }
            cpt++;
        });

        //Merging the body of the table
        cpt=0;
        $("#table1 tbody tr").each(function(i, el){


            var lines=$("#table2 tbody ").find("tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").find("td");
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                var lines=$("#table2 tbody ").find("tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").find("td").slice( 2 );
                $(this).append(lines);
            }else {
                var lines=$("#table2 tbody ").find("tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").find("td").slice(1);
                $(this).append(lines);
            }
        });
        
           })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table width="100%" id="table1"   class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
                    <td colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
                    <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
                    <td>TP s/d Bulan ini</td>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">01</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">05</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">02</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">03</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">04</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table width="100%" id="table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
                    <td colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
                    <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
                    <td>TP s/d Bulan ini</td>

                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">01</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">05</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">02</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">03</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">04</td>
                    <td>Kejadian</td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Rp</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gagantous is my answer helping ?